# Use Excel VBA to fill database with payments split in months

Tags: excel, vba, payment, finance

I'm making a spreadsheet to control my finances.
I made a VBA code where I enter 4 different data: i) Client's name; ii) Total value of the contract; iii) Number of months that the contract will be paid; iv) Date of the first payment.

I've been able to complete and use the code, that fills a database with these information in 4 different columns.

The thing is, I want it to (when I click the insert button) automatically split the value and fill the dates according to the number of months that it will be paid (payment in installments). For example:

USERFORM

1. Client name: John
2. Total value: $ 1,000.00
3. Number of payments: 4
4. Date of the first payment: 01/01/2020

That said, John will pay me $250 on 01/01/2020 (january); $250 on 02/01/2020 (february) and so on... and I want it to show on the data base something like this:

| Client | Value | Date - mm/dd/yyyy |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Claire | 2,000 | 12/05/2019 (example of a single payment on database) |
| John | 250 | 01/01/2020 |
| John | 250 | 02/01/2020 |
| John | 250 | 03/01/2020 |
| John | 250 | 04/01/2020 |
| Mark | 500 | 06/02/2020 (example) |

And I don't have a clue how to do this... Can someone help me?

The code is:

```
Private Sub cmdAdd_Click()

Dim iRow As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = Worksheets("Projetos")

'find first empty row in database
iRow = ws.Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlRows, _
    SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Row + 1
    
'copy the data to the database
With ws
  .Cells(iRow, 2).Value = Me.boxCliente.Value
  .Cells(iRow, 3) = CCur(boxValor.Value)
  .Cells(iRow, 4).Value = Me.boxParcela.Value
  .Cells(iRow, 5) = CDate(boxData.Value)
End With

'clear the data
Me.boxCliente.Value = ""
Me.boxValor.Value = ""
Me.boxParcela.Value = ""
Me.boxData.Value = ""

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this code.

Its always possible to optimize this. Maybe a little bugfix its possible. But without a text datasheet its not clear.

```
Private Sub cmdAdd_Click()

Dim iRow As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim Name a string
Dim counter As Integer
Dim money As Double
Dim Date as Date
Dim i As Integer

Set ws = Worksheets("Projetos")

'find first empty row in database
iRow = ws.Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlRows, _
    SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Row + 1
    
'copy the data to the database
With ws
  .Cells(iRow, 2).Value = Me.boxCliente.Value 'Client
  .Cells(iRow, 3) = CCur(boxValor.Value) 'Money
  .Cells(iRow, 4).Value = Me.boxParcela.Value 'Number of Payments
  .Cells(iRow, 5) = CDate(boxData.Value) 'Date
  
  If .Cells(iRow, 4) <> 1 Then
    Name = .Cells(iRow, 2).Value
    counter = .Cells(iRow, 4).Value
    money = .Cells(iRow, 3).Value
    Date = .Cells(iRow, 5).Value
    
    For i = 0 To counter - 1
        .Cells(iRow + i, 2).Value = Name
        .Cells(iRow + i, 3).Value = money / counter
        .Cells(iRow + i, 5).Value = Format(DateAdd("m", i, Date), "mmddyyyy")
    Next i
        
End With

'clear the data
Me.boxCliente.Value = ""
Me.boxValor.Value = ""
Me.boxParcela.Value = ""
Me.boxData.Value = ""

End Sub
```

Comment: Wow! That worked like a charm!
Thank you so much!
I just had to make a few things to make it work. Thank you, Thank you